# Как задать условия для произвольных полей по маске?

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте **wordpress** есть у меня конкретные произвольные поля вида `shop_*`

```
<p><a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="//<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'shop_megazap', true); ?>/search/simple/?query=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_vendor_code', true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'shop_megazap', true); ?></a></p>
<p><a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="//<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'shop_autosup', true); ?>/search/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_vendor_code', true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'shop_autosup', true); ?></a></p>
```

Как задать универсальное правило для любых произвольных полей с основой в названии **shop_***

```
else if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'shop_*', true)== 'shop_*') {
<p><a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="//<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'shop_*', true); ?>/search/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_vendor_code', true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'shop_*', true); ?></a></p>
}
```

Comment: я про вордпресс ниче не знаю, поэтому вопрос - проблема в get_post_meta или в проверке?

Comment: в проверке. `get_post_meta` для кокретных запросов отрабатывает хорошо, а вот как ей подсунуть маску..вопрос

Comment: get_post_meta() WP 1.5.0

Возвращает значение указанного произвольного поля записи (поста). Можно получить массив всех полей записи (поста).
Для того, чтобы получить значение всех произвольных полей определенного поста, нужно оставить пустым параметр $key. Также для этого можно воспользоваться функцией get_post_custom().

Comment: получите весь массив и проверьте

Comment: @splash58  хорошо, к примеру получил. как проверить по маске?

Comment: а какой там формат результата ? киньте в идеале через var_export . Или хотя бы структуру

Comment: `if (substr($str, 0, strlen('shop_')) === 'shop_')`